# How can I show an alert only if the user visits a specific website in my app?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

How can I show the user an alert if they visit `https://google.com`, `https://duckduckgo.com`, `https://bing.com` or `https://yandex.ru`, but don't show anything when they visit any other website?

I have tried this, but no success. (This is just a part of my code)

```
var isSearchEngine="NO"

if urlString!.contains("https://google.com") {
        var isSearchEngine="YES"
    } else {
        var isSearchEngine="NO"
    }
    
    if urlString!.contains("https://duckduckgo.com") {
        var isSearchEngine="YES"
    } else {
        var isSearchEngine="NO"
    }
    
    if urlString!.contains("https://yandex.ru") {
        var isSearchEngine="YES"
    } else {
        var isSearchEngine="NO"
    }
    
    if urlString!.contains("https://bing.com") {
        var isSearchEngine="YES"
    } else {
        var isSearchEngine="NO"
    }
    
    if isHub=="YES" {
        Debug.log("Visited search engine website.")
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Search Engine Detected", message: "The website you visited is a search engine.", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    } else {
        Debug.log("Didn't visit a Search engine website.")
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No search engine", message: "The website you visited isn't a search engine.", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
```

Every time I run my app with this code, I always get the "No Search Engine" alert, no matter what website I visit. Always "No search engine". Can anyone help me? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Where have you implemented this code?  Are you using a web view in your app?

Comment: Hint: webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)

Comment: @Paulw11 This is in ViewController.swift. Yes, my app is a browser and I just started experimenting with Alerts. Also, I have added more info in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not make sense as written. It executes a series of if/else expressions one after the other. If the URL contains "https://google.com" for example, the first if/else statement would set `isSearchEngine` to true, and then the very next if/else statement would set it back to false.

Rewrite it. Something like this would work:

```
var isSearchEngine = false

if let notNilURLString = urlString {
    let searchEngineURLs = [
       "https://google.com", 
       "https://yandex.ru", 
       "https://duckduckgo.com"] // And so on
    for searchEngineURL in searchEngineURLs {
        if notNilURLString.contains(searchEngineURL)
           isSearchEngine = true
        }
    }
}
```

Second problem: After trying to set `isSearchEngine = true` when you detect the URL for a search engine, the rest of your code goes on to check if a string isHub=="YES", completely ignoring the value of `isSearchEngine`.

Third point: Use the `Bool` type for true/false, not strings containing "YES" and "NO".

Comment: Also, setting `var isSearchEngine="YES"` inside the if statement isn't actually modifying the existing variable.

Comment: @JamesP Oops. I should have looked at the OPs code more closely before editing it. Thanks for catching that. I fixed it. (I also switched `isSearchEngine` to a `Bool`)

Comment: On Second problem: Oh sorry, I accidentally merged isHub from another project I had open . I am an absolute beginner with Swift, so I'm learning. Also, when I use your code, I get an error saying "Cannot find urlString in scope". Does that mean I didn't give it a value at the beginning? urlString is set to the website an user visits when they enter it then press Return. So when the website loads, urlString is passed over to WKWebView to load its contents (the user-specified URL).

Comment: UPDATE: I have managed to get rid of that by moving the code somewhere else in the file. No compiler errors now, but I only see the No Search Engine alert after visiting any website. Here's what I've done: https://codeshare.io/OdKZ60 Thanks for the help along the way!